# Mobile App Salesforce Sync

Tags: apex, mobile, class

I have an mobile app which can work offline. What i need is a guidness. I need to insert     my object which already created on my mobile device, to salesforce WITHOUT smartstore. Can you please show me a way to deal with it or maybe you can suggest an essay, web page to read about or sample code..
I need to deal with it ASAP but i couldnt. I have tried to use upsert on my custom class.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can persist your object offline however you like, e.g. using Core Data or a SQLite DB in an iOS app.

When the user's device has connectivity restored and you want to upsert your record to salesforce, you have to upsert to one of the known object types in the user's org. That's just a standard upsert or create operation like any other.

If you're upserting a custom object, you still need to fulfill all requirements (validation rules, triggers, etc) even if the object was initially created offline.

Comment: I completely understood what u mean actually i think i should be more spesific about my problem..I have and examination object in the both mobile app and salesforce org, and also i have result object again in the both side. Examination and result objects are related. I couldn't deal with Id fields. ExaminationId has to be not null on the result object. I am so confused as u can see i couldnt even explain it smoothly. I thought i can generate JSON and then parse that JSON add a List of parsed JSON insert that List to SF it goes on.This sunday is my deadline and i have no idea what should i do..

Comment: You have to populate your lookup field with an ID. If your two objects are related, you must first insert one of them, receive its ID, then use that ID in the lookup field in the other object.